# MATLAB: solving symbolic matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, equation, symbolic-math

I've got three matrixes, one of which contains the unknowns. Two of them are multiplied by each other and result the last one.

```
A1 * A2 = A3
```

So, I've got this code in MATLAB:

```
syms A1 A2 A3 B C D F
k1=1; k2=2, b=3, a=4

A1 = [ -exp(i*k1*b) exp(-k2*b) exp(k2*b) 0; i*k1*exp(i*k1*b) k2*exp(-k2*b) -k2*exp(k2*b) 0; 0 -exp(-k2*a) -exp(k2*a) (exp(-i*k1*a) + exp(i*k1*a)); 0 -k2*exp(-k2*a) k2*exp(k2*a) i*k1*(exp(-i*k1*a) - exp(i*k1*a)) ]
A2 = [ B; C; D; F ]
A3 = [ exp(-i*k1*b) ; i*k1*exp(-i*k1*b) ; 0 ; 0 ]
```

I want to solve what's the result of B, C, D and F. I know I've got to use function `solve` but I got problem with the syntax all the time.

Thanks for your time and reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has no need for any symbolic mathematics.  Your `A1` and `A3` matrices are defined numerically.  All you have to do to find the entries in `A2` is to invoke the inverse operator (`\`) between `A1` and `A3`.  Specifically, if you are given:

```
A1 * A2 = A3   ,
```

to find `A2`, you would do:

```
A2 = A1^{-1} * A3
```

You would find the inverse of `A1` and multiply this with `A3`.  You can easily do this in MATLAB by the inverse operator:

```
A2 = A1 \ A3;
```

Therefore, just do this:

```
k1=1; k2=2; b=3; a=4;

A1 = [ -exp(i*k1*b) exp(-k2*b) exp(k2*b) 0; i*k1*exp(i*k1*b) k2*exp(-k2*b) -k2*exp(k2*b) 0; 0 -exp(-k2*a) -exp(k2*a) (exp(-i*k1*a) + exp(i*k1*a)); 0 -k2*exp(-k2*a) k2*exp(k2*a) i*k1*(exp(-i*k1*a) - exp(i*k1*a)) ]
A3 = [ exp(-i*k1*b) ; i*k1*exp(-i*k1*b) ; 0 ; 0 ]
A2 = A1 \ A3;
```

`A2` will compute `B`, `C`, `D` and `F` for you.  Just refer to the first, second, third and fourth elements of `A2` respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much! So simple but so needed.

Comment: @Katt - You're welcome :)  It just comes with experience and years of playing around with MATLAB.  Don't overcomplicate the problem is my #1 rule.  Good luck!